# AVAudioPlayer initWithURL not working to stream radio

Tags: ios, url, avaudioplayer, internet-radio

I'm trying to stream an radio in my app.

I'm using AVAudioPlayer, but I have an error I don't understand :

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://broadcast.infomaniak.net/radionova-high.mp3";
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSError *error;
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL error:&error];

if (self.audioPlayer == nil){
    NSLog(@"Error loading clip: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
else {
    self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    self.audioPlayer.volume = 0.5;
    [self.audioPlayer play];
}
```

And I have the following error :

```
Error loading clip: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)
```

Does anyone see what's wrong ?

**EDIT :**

This is what the Apple docs say:

> The AVAudioPlayer class does not provide support for streaming audio
>   based on HTTP URL's. The URL used with initWithContentsOfURL: must be
>   a File URL (file://). That is, a local path.

Now what ? :(

Answer (score 0):

download file to document directoty then play file

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://broadcast.infomaniak.net/radionova-high.mp3";
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
        NSString *docDirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp3", docDirPath , fileName];
        [audioData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

        NSError *error;
        NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
        self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];
        if (self.audioPlayer == nil) {
            NSLog(@"AudioPlayer did not load properly: %@", [error description]);
        } else {
       self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;
      self.audioPlayer.volume = 0.5;
            [self.audioPlayer play];
        }
```

Comment: I see. But it's a radio stream... I can't download the file, can I ?

Comment: It runs unlimitedly this line: `NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];` and never gets to go to the next one.

Comment: It's not corrupted. MP3 radio streams run endlessly. The dataWithContentsOfURL: method only returns once the HTTP request ends. In this case, the HTTP connection is never closed by the server, and so the method never returns.